# YUI dialog and Javascript state caching

Tags: javascript, yui

When using [YUI calendar inside YUI dialog](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/calcontainer_clean.html) the js state is not cached in Firefox: pick a date, it gets populated into the field, navigate to another page and then click back, the form is reset. Do the same in IE and the selected date will be retained.

What is a workaround to this problem?

**EDIT:**
It appears that `YAHOO.util.Event._simpleRemove(window, "unload", YAHOO.util.Event._unload);` per [this YUI ticket](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/ticket/2091763), is the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually going answer my own question, because it seems that `YAHOO.util.Event._simpleRemove(window, "unload", YAHOO.util.Event._unload);` is in fact the answer for both broswers.